# How to store co-ordinates of all shapes on a canvas

Tags: processing

I am trying to create a sketch which consists of randomly placed lines with random angulations and strokeWeight. The idea is that at each frame the lines change their tilt slightly according to a preset rule which in turn depends on the strokeWeight and other parameters. To do this I think I need to record the co-ordinates of each line at setup and then transform them and then record them again. If that makes sense. 
Basically the question boils down to how can I record the co-ordinates of all the lines on a canvas?

Here is what I have written so far but how do I store the shape co-ordinates:

```java
//Sets up the random lines on the canvas
//Sets up the authorities (line widths)
//Sets up the connections between lines
void setup() {
  background(204);
  size(800, 800); 
   for (int x=1;x <1000;x +=1){
     fill(75, 70, 80);
     //For the x y cords
  float r = random(800);
  float s = random(800);
  //for the strokeWeight
  float fat = random(5);
  //for the stroke colour which varies with stroke weight
  float col = random(350);
  float red = random(350);
  float g = random(350);
  float b = random(350);
  //for the initial tilt 
  float rot = random(360);


  //stroke(242, 204, 47, 255);
  strokeWeight(fat);
   //stroke (red,green,blue,opacity)
  stroke(fat*100, 180, 180);
  //stroke(242, 204, 47, 255);
  line(r,s,r+10,s+10);
  rotate(radians(rot));
}
}



//This part is the diffusion animation
void draw() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a `Line` class that holds the information necessary to draw a line. Something like this:

```java
class Line{
   float x1, y1, x2, y2;

   public Line(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
   }

   public void draw(){
      line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
   }

   public boolean intersects(Line other){
      //left as exercise for reader
   }
}
```

Then you can randomly generate lines:

```java
ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

void setup(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      lines.add(new Line(random(width), random(height), random(width), random(height));
   }
}

void draw(){
   background(0);
   for(Line line : lines){
      line.draw();
   }
}
```

This is what I was getting at when I told you in your other question that you need to create a data structure and store your line coordinates. From here you can write logic that moves your lines around, or detects intersections, etc.

Comment: Great. I had to move the for(Line line: lines){ etc. block to setup as otherwise it seemed to continuously draw random lines with the result that the canvas became black. Otherwise perfect. I'm learning....

Comment: @SebastianZeki That's not what my code does. That would only happen if you removed my call to `background(0)` and then moved the randomization of the lines into their `draw()` function, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Ahhhh. Thank you Kevin. Sorted now